# Using PyPylon API in tandem with pylon viewer

Tags: python, basler

This feels like a simple question, but I haven't been able to parse this out from the pypylon documentation. Is there a way to acquire a single image from a camera that's actively connected to the pylon viewer? or is there a way in pypylon to disconnect the camera from pylon viewer? We are using the viewer for aligning during setup, but we want to acquire an image during the process for passing to openCV.

I've been able to connect and acquire images with pylon viewer closed, but not once it's open and has the camera active.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

As the rule of thumb, only one user's application can have access to camera, and every time it's an exclusive access, that's obvious.

But.

For GigE based cameras, there is [a functionality of broadcast/multicast](https://docs.baslerweb.com/pylonapi/cpp/pylon_advanced_topics#gige-multicastbroadcast-grab-images-of-one-camera-on-multiple-computers) by which you can theoretically feed your secondary application with the stream from already initialized camera. Pypylon package currently should have this functionality working:
https://github.com/basler/pypylon/issues/248

Hope it helps.